# How to query selecting name with specific code in field and the same time has no code in the same field

Tags: mysql, sql

Example of my table

```
Name    Code
Jolas   sd02
Jolas   da014
Albert  cca01
Albert  da014
Julito  sd02
Julito  da014
Vergel  cca01
Vergel  da014
```

I want to select all da014 without sd02, so my output should be Vergel and Albert because both of them has no SD02

How should i query it

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation based filtering using `GROUP BY` with `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT Name
FROM your_table_name 
GROUP BY Name
HAVING 
  SUM(Code = 'da014') AND /* Has code `da014` */
  NOT SUM(Code = 'sd02') /* Does not have code sd02 */
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer is there any different with this query

select * from mytable where code='da014' and name not in (select name from mytable where code='sd02')..

Comment: @albertDaracan performance difference will be huge when you have a bigger data. You can check `EXPLAIN` statement results.

Comment: Okay Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 0):

I generally prefer the `group by` approach for these types of problems.  But if performance is an issue, then this might be faster with the right indexes:

```
select t.name
from t
where t.code = 'da014' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.code = 'sd02');
```

In particular, you want indexes on `t(code, name)` and `t(name, code)` -- one is for the outer query and one is for the subquery.

If you do use `group by`, then filtering before the aggregation can help performance:

```
select t.name
from t
where t.code in ('da014', 'sd02')
group by t.name
having sum(t.code = 'sd02') = 0;
```

You only have to check `'sd02'`.  If it is not there, then `name` must have the other code to be processed by the `group by`.